cd doesn't appear to be changing directory in terminal
I have a weird issue that I first noticed in VS Code but can replicate in terminal, and it's that when I try to cd to a folder, nothing happens. Here's my terminal output to demonstrate:
rh-macbook@AS1554 ~ % pwd
/Users/rh-macbook
rh-macbook@AS1554 ~ % ls
Applications        Library         Public
Desktop         Movies          node_modules
Documents       Music           package-lock.json
Downloads       Pictures        package.json
rh-macbook@AS1554 ~ % cd Desktop
rh-macbook@AS1554 ~ % ls
Applications        Library         Public
Desktop         Movies          node_modules
Documents       Music           package-lock.json
Downloads       Pictures        package.json

Here's an example from within VS Code on a demo project
rh-macbook@AS1554 website-demo % pwd
/Users/rh-macbook/Desktop/Repos/website-demo
rh-macbook@AS1554 website-demo % ls
README.md       my-app
rh-macbook@AS1554 website-demo % cd my-app
rh-macbook@AS1554 website-demo % ls
README.md       my-app
rh-macbook@AS1554 website-demo % 

This is a work-issued laptop but I seem to be the only person with this issue.
Device: M2 Pro 16GB
MacOS: Sonoma 14.6.1 (23G93)
I've tried cd /Desktop, cd desktop, cd ~/Desktop and all variations. It just does not seem to be switching the folder.
There is no error code.
rh-macbook@AS1554 ~ % echo $?
0
rh-macbook@AS1554 ~ % echo $HOME
/Users/rh-macbook


Answer:
As per the answer below, cd had been aliased to cdnvm. This happened when I followed the instructions on NVM's readme to automatically change node versions per .nvmrc file. Running this command fixed it:
unalias cd

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/why-is-cd-not-a-program

You tagged this [tag:bash] but the prompt suggests you are using [tag:zsh]. Please don't mix these two up; they are two different shells.

Check what is output of which cd. Looks like either your cd binary is corrupted or some alias is running instead of cd itself.
P.S. - It was alias issue. output of which cd was aliased to cdnvm

You absolute beauty of a human being.
rh-macbook@AS1554 ~ % which cd cd: aliased to cdnvm
Thank you!

happy to help. BTW, what is cdnvm?

It was an alias that was created when seeing up NVM auto-switching Node version based on a .nvmrc file in the project. I have no idea why it aliases cd to the bash script it creates.
